# Java .war deployment issues on jboss-as-7.1.1.Final

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, classpath, jboss7.x, manifest

I am working on a dynamic web project (`StudentManagement.war`) which relies on an `EJB` (`StudentManagementEJB.jar`) for database interfacing. The `EJB` project has been added to the web project's class path. On deployment, however, the following exceptions are thrown:

```
22:23:21,275 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."StudentManagement.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."StudentManagement.war".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "StudentManagement.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error getting reflective information for class student.management.ManageStudentServlet with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.StudentManagement.war:main" from Service Module Loader
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:70) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.metadata.MethodAnnotationAggregator.runtimeAnnotationInformation(MethodAnnotationAggregator.java:58)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.handleAnnotations(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:85)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:70)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:55)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lstudent/management/ManageStudentSessionBeanLocal;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:57) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:66) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: student.management.ManageStudentSessionBeanLocal from [Module "deployment.StudentManagement.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    ... 15 more
```

This shows that the web module cannot find classes defined within the bean. I've changed my default: `%JBOSS_HOME%\standalone\deployments\StudentManagement.war\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF` to:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path:  file:/C:/Utils/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/deployments/StudentManagementEJB.jar
```

In spite of this the exception persists. There are two spaces between **Class-Path:** and the URI and a space after the end of the URI(../standalone) followed by a new line character.

Is there something wrong in my syntax?
 I am using java ee 7, jboss-as-7.1.1.Final and Win 7 x64.

Comment: Can you include the .jar file in the .war ?

Comment: You have packaged the class with the EJB jar so it's available only within the EJB module and not within the WAR module. To make it available within both the EJB and the WAR modules then you have to package it with the EAR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the StudentManagementEJB.jar file is not copied into the /lib directory upon deployment. Aside from adding it to the Class-Path, it must also be copied to

`%JBOSS_HOME%\standalone\deployments\<ProjectName>.war\WEB-INF\lib`

directory(if the project is deployed as .war). In this case ProjectName is StudentManagement.

Answer (score 0):

Do not reference to the deployments-folder (standalone/deployments). The deployed applications are not really deployed there, but copied from there to the data-directory, or they are not even in the deployments-folder, if you use other forms of deployment, e.g. jboss-cli.bat

There are some ways you can solve this.

1) Don't package the EJB separately, but include it into the WAR (the easiest).

2) Create an EAR and package the WAR and EJB-JAR together into the EAR (the classic).

3) Create a module from the interface-classes and reference from EJB.jar and WAR to the module. See e.g. "Dependencies:" in https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Class+Loading+in+AS7

4) Reference in the WARs MANIFEST to the EJB-deployment like:

```
Dependencies:deployment.StudentManagementEJB.jar
```

From https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Class+Loading+in+AS7:

> Module names for top level deployments follow the format
>   deployment.myarchive.war while sub deployments are named like
>   deployment.myear.ear.mywar.war.
>
> This means that it is possible for a deployment to import classes from
>   another deployment using the other deployments module name, the
>   details of how to add an explicit module dependency are explained
>   below.